# How to get the AzServiceBusKey from azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run the below command in powershell to get the AzServiceBusKey from my azure subscription

Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroupName ts-encompass-bj -Namespace ts-encompass-sb-bj -Name "RootSend"

It throws the error: Get-AzServiceBusKey: Error converting value "The requested resource RootSend does not exist." to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.ErrorResponseContent'.

Not sure what is this Name property here and how it is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Name` is the AuthorizationRule Name. Something like RootManageSharedAccessKey:

[image]